# android webserver for mysql database tutorial

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I have an Android application. This app currently connects with a mysql database using various .php files. I think that when many users access my app at the same time, it will impact the performance of the app, soi want to get rid of all .php files and create a webservice to make the connection between my app and my mysql database. Is there any tutorial i can follow that can help me create this webservice? It can be REST or any other, i just want my android app to connect with it and i want it to connect with my database. I will need GET/POST/DELETE operations.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would recommend is similar to [this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-part-1/). Basically, you code your REST webservice methods in a separate Java application which would connect to your database. Your android application would consume the webservice, just like in the tutorial.

The tutorial uses a third party library, which I don't think is necessary, as you can use Android's AsyncTask and do the same thing. Also, keep in mind that HttpClient is deprecated and was replaced with HttpURLConnection.